# nifi splitRecord hung

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm testing nifi SplitRecord with a small file of only 11 records
However, SplitRecord hangs for a long time. I don't get a clue what it is doing.
[Processor Hung](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzYlU.png)

[SPlitRecord Properties:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLbJ0.png)
[more properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qTBw.png)

Is Records Per Split controlling
the maximum, or the minimum, or exact number of records per split?
if the total number of records is less than records per split, what's the behavior of SplitRecords? does it wait until a time-out and then put all on-hold records in to a single split?

After about 10 minutes or random number of start/stop/terminate/restart
it may trigger the processor to split the data sooner.

Comment: Please include all of the SplitRecord properties, not just a single property

Comment: Hi the other properties are just Record Reader and Record Writer, which are modified avroreader and writer.

Comment: Thanks - what do you mean by 'modified'? It looks like you're on NiFi 1.8, do you have scope to upgrade? 1.8 is from 2018, so quite old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Records Per Split controls the maximum, see "[SplitRecord.java](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/753c311382005acadc16c64952d7b1eaaf2550d5/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/SplitRecord.java#L177)" for the code. If there are fewer records than the `RECORDS_PER_SPLIT` value, it will immediately push them all out.

However, it does look like it is creating a *new* FlowFile, even if the total record count is less than the `RECORDS_PER_SPLIT` value, meaning it's doing disk writing regardless of whether a split really occured.

I would probably investigate two things:

1. Host memory - how much memory does the host have? How much is configured as NiFi max heap? How much total system memory is in use/free? NiFi performs best when plenty of system memory is left for file cache.
2. Host's disks, specifically the disk that has the Content Repository on it. Capacity? IO? Is it shared with other services? FlowFile content is written to the Content Repository, if the disk is shared with the OS, or other busy services (or other NiFi repos) it can really slow content modification down.

*Note*: your NiFi version over 3 years old, please consider upgrading.

Comment: based on my testing, it seems that it will wait for Records Per Split or a time out (approx. 10 minutes)?

Comment: Points taken. We are in process of upgrading nifi.

Comment: If there are fewer Records than the Records Per Split value, it will immediately push them all out.  <== how does it decide there will be more records coming or that's all to be split. Thx.

Comment: If you take a look at the code I linked, it cuts a set of Records up to the Max Records `final RecordSet limitedSet = pushbackSet.limit(maxRecords);` , which it stores in a ArrayList of FlowFiles `final List<FlowFile> splits = new ArrayList<>();`. It keeps cutting sets of Records, until there are no Records left `while (pushbackSet.isAnotherRecord())`. When then there are no Records left, it writes the ArrayList of FlowFiles out to the split relationship `session.transfer(splits, REL_SPLITS);`